# Mark Read all the unread channel's in a getStream chat app

Tags: node.js

I'm working with a React Native mobile app and there is a chat functionality with the getstream. There are several workspaces and that contains several channels. There is a functionality to disable the chat functionality of the workspaces.

In my backend part (Node.js), when I disable the chat of the workspace, I need to unread count get to 0 of the all channels in the workspace. To do this, I try the below code.

```
// Channel state disable/enable - update channel and mark read channel's unread messages
const channelSetStateByWorkspaceId = async (workspace_id, state) =\> {
    console.log('Call the channelSetStateByWorkspaceID function--\>\>');
    const chatClient = getGetStreamClient();
    const sort = \[{ last_message_at: -1 }\];
    const filter = { type: "team", workspace_id: workspace_id };
    const channels = await chatClient.queryChannels(filter, sort, {});
    channels.map(async (channel) =\> {
        await channel.updatePartial({ set: { disabled: state } });
        await channel.markAllRead()
        .then(() =\> {
            console.log('All messages marked as read.--\>\>');
        })
        .catch((error) =\> {
            console.error('Error marking messages as read:--\>\>', error);
        });
    });
};
```

Expectation - badge count to - 0 of the workspace when I disable the chat of the workspace. `your text`

Comment: Missing indentation in code (revision 1 and revision 2) is often a sign it has been copied from somewhere, e.g., from a web page. Is that the case?

Comment: Some  of this is incomprehensible, e.g., near "I need to unread". Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76242394/edit)? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: Is escaping with "\" actually supposed to be part of the code? Examples: `\[`, `\]`, and `\>`. Or part of the said hypothetical web page's escape mechanism? (Not rhetorical questions.)